# sh не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: cmd, selenium

Пытаюсь запустить Selenium сервер. Пишет: sh не является внутренней или внешней командой.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Не запускать linux-лаунчер на машине с windows. Опишите, откуда вы взяли дистрибутив и как его запускаете.

Answer (score 2):

Сам решил. Нужно было указать в PATH путь к sh.exe